# Why would anybody pay the toll if an alternate road already exists?

Tags: plot-explanation, in-time

In the film [*In Time* (2011)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637688/), it is shown that the toll rates are very high to get to the city area from the ghetto. But later, it is also shown that there is an alternate route for people to use which is ***free*** to use.

Why, then, does anybody need to use the road which requires payment?

Comment: In the case of real life toll roads that parallel free but congested roads the answer is simple: *speed*.

Comment: You know the same situation exists in the world, today, with each and every road that charges a toll, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It comes down to the alternate routes might take a much longer time to use.  Whether it be traffic or just the distance you travel in order to get out of paying a few hours (dollars), it might be just more worth their *time* to pay up.